# Clear focus from search view

Tags: android, searchview

I'am using search view , i want  the search icon to be at the right of the search view and clear focus from search view in the beginning

here is my search view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/searchView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        app:searchIcon="@drawable/search_icon"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

i put the search icon on the right by using this code below

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

and it worked , but how i can make keyboard disappears ?

any help?

Comment: set  search.onActionViewCollapsed();

Answer (score 0):

To set the icon to the right :

You can do it programmatically :

```
 SearchView search = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
 search.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
```

To Hide the keyboard :

- in your manifest file (manifest.xml) :

  ```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
  ```

Or

- in your java Code

  ```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
  ```